# how to fetch data from database in odoo 9

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9

I have a piece of code for fetching data, but it did not work

py file

```
 class group_js(osv.osv):
    _name = "group_js"
    _description = "Group JS"

    _columns={
       'id': fields.integer('ID', readonly=True),
       'name': fields.char('Purpose', required=True, select=1),
       'js' : fields.text('Javascript',required = True , index=True,store=True),
       'active' : fields.boolean('Active'),
       'group_id': fields.many2many('res.groups', 'js_group_rel', 'js_group_id', 'group_id', string='Groups'),
    }
   _sql_constraints = [
    ('name_uniq', 'unique (name)', 'The name of the Javascript available , You must change your javascript name or check the javascript code may available !!!')
   ]

   def get_record(self,cr,uid,context=None):
     get_obj=self.pool.get('group_js')
     user_ids = get_obj.browse(cr, uid,uid,[])
     return user_ids.to_JSON()

  def to_JSON(self,cr,context=None):
     return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict__, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow _"It does not work"_ is insufficient information. You must explain what exactly happens, and provide any error messages and stack trace. Please visit the [help] and also read [ask].

Comment: What are you trying to here and whats not working?

Comment: thanx@Bazzinga, Jim Garrison , exactly i want to retrieve data from database in odoo , so i follow the get_record() function , but the function does not return anything .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Browse  take  cursor, user ,**ids** , context

For ids you firstly  **search** in the model using  blank domain **[]**.

try this way:

```
   def get_record(self,cursor,user,context=None):
     get_obj=self.pool.get('group_js')
     domain=[]
     ids = get_obj.search(cursor, user,domain)
     user_ids = get_obj.browse(cursor, user,ids,context)
     return user_ids.to_JSON()
```

OR this way

```
   def get_record(self,cursor,user,context=None):
     get_obj=self.pool.get('group_js')
     domain=[]
     ids = get_obj.search(cursor, user,domain)
     user_ids = get_obj.read(cursor, user,ids,[],context)
     return user_ids
```

**EDITED : regarding how to get group name along with id**

As `group_id` is the `many2many` fields so  in that case you will have `browse` the record as below and update the group `group_id`:

```
group_obj = self.pool.get('res.groups')
def get_id_name(group_id):
    res =group_obj.browse(cursor, user,group_id)
    return res.id,res.name
user_ids[0]['group_id']=map(lambda group_id:get_id_name(group_id),user_ids[0]['group_id'])
```

Now the method will look like:

```
  def get_record(self,cursor,user,context=None):
    get_obj=self.pool.get('group_js')
    domain=[]
    ids = get_obj.search(cursor, user,domain)
    user_ids = get_obj.read(cursor, user,ids,[],context)
    group_obj = self.pool.get('res.groups')
    def get_id_name(group_id):
        res =group_obj.browse(cursor, user,group_id)
        return res.id,res.name
    user_ids[0]['group_id']=map(lambda group_id:get_id_name(group_id),user_ids[0]['group_id'])
    return user_ids
```

Comment: thanx @Sharma , it's working for me. but i have a little bit confusion ,  it don't show the groups name what we assign in my form . the field name is **group_id**

Comment: `group_id : Array[3]  
0:2  
1:10  
2:12
length:3 ` in this format the group name show . instead of group name , this 2,10,12 will be show . 2 will show for Administration / Access Rights , 10 will show for Sales / Manager and 12 will show for Other Extra Rights / Portal groups .

Comment: yes , i use the read method means get_obj.read , and that will show 
`group_id : Array[3]  0:2  1:10  2:12  length:3` ,this result instead of groups name

Comment: as group_id is a many2many fields thus it will always contain list of ids 'group_id': [1, 2, 3],

Comment: yes, i understand this but , how can i show the group name instead of ids.